# Need help avoiding a bug in Selenium, Java, where two fields are dissapearing. I need a loop that activates when the fields are missing

Tags: java, selenium

I need to avoid a bug as it will not be fixed and it is failing my test.

Imagine you have a page with some fields, two of them being a Company and a Warehouse select-type fields. 1 out of 5 tests, the two fields are not displayed due to a bug. As such, I tried to avoid it by writing something like this:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath(xMaterialNumber)).size()<=0){
        m.click(xCloseOrder);
        m.click(xOpenOrderRequest);
        m.click(xOpenOrderImport);
}
```

The if statement above closes the order and opens it again in order to avoid the bug. The problem is that the loop is never started, even though the respective fields are not displayed on the screen (which is obviously blocking my test).

Do you have any idea on how to write this so it triggers when the issue occurs?

Comment: Could you add more detail to the question regarding the system and programming framework used. *"Need help avoiding a bug"* doesn't seem like a useful question title.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, the system is a site that creates Orders. What i need is an if statement that starts the report again when the bug is encountered.

Comment: It is Eclipse with *Java* along with Selenium Server?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Tudor What is the value of size you are getting that is in the if condition when the fields are not displayed.

Comment: @Grasshopper this is going to be a little tricky to find, as it is not an 100% repro rate for it. As soon as i find out i'll post it here.

Comment: @Tudor Check this in both cases. Log it somewhere and let the test run. If you have access to the code just comment the elements out.

Comment: This is what i am doing., and i have access to the code as i'm writing it:D So, the value when the test is running just fine is 1, i'm waiting for it to fail so i can get the other value

Comment: And value from the case where it fails is 0...so why it is not entering the loop i wonder...should i write it as [blabla].size()!=1 ? Does it make any difference?

Comment: You can go with `.isEmpty()` instead of `.size()<=0`

Comment: @Madhan nicely done man! That was the solution. Now it enters the loop when the size is 0. Please post it as an answer so i can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going with `list.size()<=0`, use [`isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty()) method

> **isEmpty**
>   boolean isEmpty()
>   Returns true if this list contains no elements.
>   Specified by:
>   isEmpty in interface Collection
>   Returns:
>    true if this list contains no elements

As far as you question is concerned go with

```
    Boolean elementNotVisible;
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xMaterialNumber));
    if (elements.isEmpty()) {
        elementNotVisible = true;
    } else {
        elementNotVisible = true;
        for (WebElement element : elements) {
            if (element.isDisplayed()) {
                elementNotVisible = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (elementNotVisible) {
        m.click(xCloseOrder);
        m.click(xOpenOrderRequest);
        m.click(xOpenOrderImport);
    }
```

Comment: Actually, it's still not solved:( just encountered it again even with isEmpty...i don;t understand why

Comment: Is it possible to provide the link to the application.or check for isdisplayed of the elements

Comment: You need to login and i can't send you credentials, so no link there. what do you mean by "isdisplayed"? to write the condition with that or how?

Comment: if the `driver.findElements` is not empty then iterate through the list and check if all the `element.isDisplayed()` is true or not

Comment: I've now written the following: `int v = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xMaterialNumber)).size();
  if(v == 0){
   m.click(xCloseOrder);
   m.click(xOpenOrderRequest);
   m.click(xOpenOrderImport);
  }`. The output is 0 from the sysout, but the for loop is still not starting... I have no idea what is happening and why it's not working. Tried with boolean as well, with isDIsplayed(), still no access to the loop...

Comment: What do you mean by loop.Where is the code for that..Can you post your full/ minimal code here

Comment: By loop i mean that if statement. And the rest of the code does not have anything to do with the answer to this question.
To summarize: I need those three statements with m.blabla to be executed somehow when those fields are missing. For some reason. using .size() and .isEmpty() is not working, even though if sysout-ing their value they have the requirements for entering the loop. So i am now in need of another solution that checks if xMaterialNumber field is present, and if not executes that code.

Comment: @Tudor check the modified answer

Comment: not working, it is not executing the if loop just as before. I'm trying a while loop now to see if it works